# kivy dropdown items overlayed on button

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

My buttons are showing over top of the DropDown they are part of when my screen loads. Would like them to not do that. Images below.

kv file:

```
<MainScreen>:
BoxLayout:
    id: menu_layout
    on_parent: root.class_level_list_generator()
    Button:
        id: btn_class_dropdown
        text: 'Select a class...'
        size_hint: (.25, .25)
        on_release: dd_class.open(self)
        DropDown:
            id: dd_class
    Button:
        id: btn_level_dropdown
        text: 'Select a level...'
        size_hint: (.25, .25)
        on_release: dd_level.open(self)
        DropDown:
            id: dd_level
    Button:
        id: btn_manager
        text: 'Manage'
        size_hint: (.25, .25)
        on_release: root.f_btn_manager()
    Button:
        id: btn_exit
        text: 'Exit'
        size_hint: (.25, .25)
        on_release: app.stop()
```

python to add buttons to the dropdown:

```
for l in levels:
# manually specify button height and label it by level number
   btn = Button(text=str(l), size_hint_y=None, height=50)
   # update button text with that of selection
   btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn:         
   self.ids.dd_level.select(btn.text))
   # add button to dropdown
   self.ids.dd_level.add_widget(btn)
self.ids.dd_level.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(self.ids.btn_level_dropdown, 'text', x))
```

Would like the items of the DropDown to not show before clicking the button.

DropDown Items Not displayed properly:

[image: DropDown Items Not displayed properly]

But they work fine after clicking the DropDown button:

[image: But they work fine after clicking the DropDown button]

Answer (score 0):

my case was different as the dropdown was at the same level than my button, in yours, the dropdown is a child of the button. However, you should just need to add `on_parent: dd_level.dismiss()` to have your Button like this :

```
Button:
    id: btn_level_dropdown
    text: 'Select a level...'
    size_hint: (.25, .25)
    on_release: dd_level.open(self)
    on_parent: dd_level.dismiss()

    DropDown:
        id: dd_level
```

If this doesn't solve the issue, try putting the dropdown at the same level. In my case, this solve it.